# Car trouble starting after drive

Tags: starting

My Vw Jetta 2005 tdi starts great in the morning. But recently after a 15 minute drive, it doesn’t want to start again. It starts but shuts off. I have to wait until it cools down for it to start. I already replaced my temperature sensor and my gas pump. I don’t know that the problem is now.

Comment: By gas pump do you mean the injector pump or the fuel pump? A TDi car doesn't run on gas

Comment: I meant fuel pump. Yes.

Comment: The times I've observed a "will run then stops, won't start for a while" on a diesel car is when a blockage in the fuel lines has led to a vacuum forming in the fuelling system, starving the engine of fuel. After some time the vacuum/low pressure is resolved/dissipates and the car will run again for a while.. if your car has a hand primer pump attached to the fuel filter it can indicate this is occurring because the primer bulb/push button will be sucked flat and not able to be pumped

Comment: I also notice when I drive, sometimes the car acceleration is poorly and eventually it gains back its power.

Comment: Any smoke from the tail pipe associated with this? What Color is the smoke?